When I use \llap to overlap words, the space between the overlapped words and the rest of the text is too much: how do I fix it?
I'm trying to make a "glitchy text" effect by overlapping differently coloured copies of the same text on top of one another with some offset, and the issue is they get separated from the surrounding text by a wide margin.
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\title{glitchy text}
\author{anonymous}
\date{September 2024}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GlitchyText}{m}
{
    {
        #1
    }\llap{
        \raisebox{1pt}{\textcolor{cyan}{#1}}\hspace{-1pt}
    }\llap{
        \raisebox{-1pt}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}\hspace{1pt}
    }\llap{
        \raisebox{0pt}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}\hspace{-0.5pt}
    }\llap{
        \raisebox{0pt}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}\hspace{0,5pt}
    }\llap{
        \raisebox{-0,5pt}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}\hspace{0pt}
    }\llap{
        \raisebox{0pt}{#1}\hspace{0pt}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\subsubsection{The Issue:}
There is too much space between: the \GlitchyText{[[Glitchy Text]]}, and the rest of the text

\end{document}

How can I make the glitchy text blend naturally with the rest of the document?

you are introducing dozens of space tokens, every end of line after { or } is a space.  use % after each

Oh so THAT is why I kept seeing the % symbol at the end of lines in other people's code! Thanks a lot, I bet a lot of other issues I had will go away now that I know this.

Every endline you have in your code contributes a space in output.
You can (and should) avoid code duplication.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\title{glitchy text}
\author{anonymous}
\date{September 2024}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GlitchyText}{m}{%
  #1%
  \GlitchyTextDo{1pt}{cyan}{-1pt}{#1}%
  \GlitchyTextDo{-1pt}{red}{1pt}{#1}%
  \GlitchyTextDo{01pt}{white}{-0.5pt}{#1}%
  \GlitchyTextDo{0pt}{white}{0.5pt}{#1}%
  \GlitchyTextDo{-0.5pt}{white}{0pt}{#1}%
  \llap{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\GlitchyTextDo}{mmmm}{%
  \llap{\raisebox{#1}{\textcolor{#2}{#4}}\hspace{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

There is standard space between the \GlitchyText{[[Glitchy Text]]}
and the rest of the text

\end{document}


Your code (leaving also the useless braces you have) should be
\NewDocumentCommand{\GlitchyText}{m}
{%
    {%
        #1%
    }\llap{%
        \raisebox{1pt}{\textcolor{cyan}{#1}}\hspace{-1pt}%
    }\llap{%
        \raisebox{-1pt}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}\hspace{1pt}%
    }\llap{%
        \raisebox{0pt}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}\hspace{-0.5pt}%
    }\llap{%
        \raisebox{0pt}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}\hspace{0,5pt}%
    }\llap{%
        \raisebox{-0,5pt}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}\hspace{0pt}%
    }\llap{%
        \raisebox{0pt}{#1}\hspace{0pt}%
    }%
}


Thanks a lot for this info! Now I understand where all those weird spaces came from.

@LucaBallanzeddu Possibly a world record of unprotected endlines in a single macro.  Don't worry: everybody fell on this, even David.

@LucaBallanzeddu this is in fact the only answer egreg knows: he reposts it every other week and picks up 1.2m points in the process.
